# SQLAnywhere .NET Connection String

Tags: sqlanywhere

I'm using SAP's SQLAnywhere 17 .NET library to connect to a database (in PowerShell), but can't find anything on the internet for the connection string format.

My credentials are as follows:

- Host: 10.10.10.10:12345
- Server: testserver
- UID: DBA
- Password: 123
- Database: testdb

This string generated by SQL Central does not work; gives me "The user 'SQL Anywhere' does not exist."

```
UID=DBA;PWD=123;Server=testserver;dbn=testdb;ASTART=No;host=10.10.10.10:12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ODBC data source on your machine first.

[image]

Then in your .Net code you can use ODBC Connection, the connection string will be something like this.

```
UID=DBA;PWD=123;Server=testserver;dbn=TestDSN;
```